# Using Shiny to create a comma delimited string list

Tags: shiny

How do you handle it in Shiny when you need to append a value to an already existing output?

To simplify my problem:

I want to create a comma separated code list in a single variable ie:

02,04,05,11,31

and display the list as I go creating it.  I validate the codes as I go, that is not the problem.

I currently have a text input widget to enter my codes.
I want to append to the list the value in the text input field, every time I press an action button.

Are there any examples of how to do this?

Shiny does not like it when I try to use an output object and append something to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Paste` to do that. Im sure there are many other ways to do it, look into this example here [reactivePoll and reactiveFileReader](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/reactive-poll-and-file-reader.html) in the gallery section. Below are a sample code where I simply print out the `Sys.time()` and append it to the last entry.

Here are two examples:

**Example 1 without the button**

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(ui = fluidRow(wellPanel(verbatimTextOutput("my_text"))), 

server = function(input, output, session) {
    autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(1000,session)
    my_file <- as.character(Sys.time())
    output$my_text <- renderText({
      autoInvalidate()
      my_file <<- paste(my_file,as.character(Sys.time()),  sep=",")
    })
  })
)
```

**Example 2 with the ActionButton**

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(ui = fluidRow(actionButton("push","Append"),wellPanel(verbatimTextOutput("my_text"))), 

server = function(input, output, session) {

my_file <- as.character(Sys.time())
output$my_text <- renderText({

if(input$push==0)
{
 return(my_file)
}
isolate({
input$push
my_file <<- paste(my_file,as.character(Sys.time()),  sep=",")              
  })
 })
})
)
```